# Understanding Proof of Hopcroft & Karps Matching Algorithm

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms

[Hopcroft & Karps algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm#Augmenting_paths) to compute a maximum matching takes $\mathcal O(mn^{1/2})$ time, which is composed by $\mathcal O(n^{1/2})$ iterations and each iteration taking $\mathcal O(m)$.

In my lecture script it says $\mathcal O(n^{1/2})$ iterations is bases on the fact that there are "relativly" short $M$-augmenting paths of maximal length of $2\cdot \lfloor |M|/ (s - |M|) \rfloor +  1$.

I am having trouble understanding this upper bound for a path's length.

Remarks:

- $G = (V, E)$ with $V = U \cup W$ bipartite graph
- $s \le n = |V|$ cardinality of a maximum matching $S$
- $M$ any matching in $G$

Moreover, I know that

- After every iteration there are no shortest path of length $l$ anymore.
- shortest $M$-augmenting paths extend by the additive factor of 2, since they always have odd length.
- Matching $|M \triangle P| =  |M| + 1$ where $\triangle$ is the symmetric difference of a matching $ M$ and a $M$-augmenting Path $P$

Comment: If you look at the original [paper by Hopcroft and Karp](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/0202019), they prove this on page 227.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that at a given stage taking the symmetric difference between the partial matching and an optimal matching gives disjoint augmenting paths and alternating cycles.

At iteration $l$ all augmenting paths are of length bigger or equal to $l$.

At this stage if there are $s-|M|$  disjoint augmenting paths and say the $i$th path uses $L_i$ matched edges, then $L_i \geq (l-1)/2$ matched edges, and thus 
$(s-|M|) (l-1)/2 \leq \sum_i L_i \leq |M|$
and solving for $l$ tells you how large $l$ could possibly be.